Does the RPi 5 + Official Active Cooler fit in the official case?
Is this the best place to ask this? I figure it anyone knows, y'all would.
I want to experiment with LLM models running on the Pi, and figure the active cooler will be helpful. And since I've killed a few pis in my life by carelessly shorting them out, the prudent part of my brain suggests a case.
I know all you badass makers have a 3d printer humming away in your basement, but I don't, so, uh, case?

I have a collection of official cases for various Pi - all now in my junk box as they are rubbish, so I didn't get conned by the Pi5 version. I use https://core-electronics.com.au/slim-case-for-raspberry-pi-5.html but there are plenty of others.

Two seconds after I posted this pouring over the AdaFruit page I see:


Fits perfectly into Raspberry Pi 5 Case


Okay, so yes.
